# How to retrieve data from firebase to Google chart?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-visualization

Sorry but it's my first project with Firebase. I try this solution in my project but to no avail (from antoher post on Stack overflow). Data for this database are from ESP8266. My Firebase looks like this:

```
"MOIST" : {
    "-MvDCD_qVJUZtZ9Pe98p" : {
      "data" : "2022-2-6",
      "time" : "09:44:40",
      "value" : 5
    },
    "-MvDCE56y_4aXngGtQJx" : {
      "data" : "2022-2-6",
      "time" : "09:44:42",
      "value" : 5
    },
```

This is the code I am using:

```
 <html>
 <head> 
     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.8/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src=" http://www.google.com/uds/modules/gviz/gviz-api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyD0y-idPsXKkqOI8333yQE9NTTvF5cDh0M",
            authDomain: "podlewanie-2.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://podlewanie-2-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
            projectId: "podlewanie-2",
            storageBucket: "podlewanie-2.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "266746962201",
            appId: "1:266746962201:web:1a4c60a5824162c560a588",
            measurementId: "G-7QW1Z2DD7W"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var database = firebase.database();


        firebase.database().ref('/MOIST').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            temps = snapshot.val();
            console.log(temps);

            google.charts.load('current', {
                'packages': ['corechart', 'line']
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(temps));
        });

        function parse(temp) {
            return (new Date(temp.replace(/-/g, '/'))).getTime()
        }



        function drawChart(temps) {
            var array = $.map(temps, function(value, index) {
                return [value];
            });

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('number', 'date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'time');
            data.addColumn('number', 'value');

            var sort = function(a, b) {
                return parse(a.time) - parse(b.time)
            };
            var tempData = array.sort(sort);
            var output = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {
                var item = tempData[i];
                output.push([
                    //  parseFloat(parse(item.time)),
                    parseFloat(item.time),
                    parseFloat(item.date),
                    parseFloat(item.value)
                ]);
            }
            console.log(output);
            data.addRows(output);


            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'title',
                    subtitle: 'subtitle'
                },
                width: 900,
                height: 500
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            console.log("data + options: " + data, options)
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }



        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['corechart', 'line']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    </script>
</head>
      <body>
        <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
      </body>
</html>
```

After run this code i see only white page. I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you see a white screen, check your browser's console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in most browsers, or <kbd>F12</kbd> in LegacyEdge/IE) for errors. In this case, you get this error:

> Uncaught Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com

This indicates that the version of the Firebase SDK you are using doesn't understand the value you gave for `databaseURL` in your configuration:

```js
var config = {
  /* ... */
  databaseURL: "https://podlewanie-2-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"
  /* ... */
}
```

Because this was probably copied straight from the Firebase Console, ask yourself *why* doesn't the SDK understand this URL? The answer to that is because you are using Firebase SDK v3.7.8 (from April 2017).

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.8/firebase.js"></script>
```

You should be using the latest version to make sure you are up-to-date on any security fixes, corrected flaws, updated server APIs or new product updates.

The latest legacy SDK (as of the time of writing) is 8.10.1 (January 2022):

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

However, for all new projects you should use the new modular SDK by following the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade). The latest version for that SDK is 9.6.6 (February 2022).

### Other issues

Aside from that, you also need to correct this line, that should be setting a callback function:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(temps));
```

to the following:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => drawChart(temps));
```

Additionally, in that `drawChart` function, you are also targetting an element with the ID `chart_div` instead of the correct `curve_chart` on this line:

```js
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

That line should be:

```js
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The tip for the SDK version is right. Now the chart is working.

Comment: This is ok `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => drawChart(temps));` but this code `var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));` make erorr.